# Loading screens one after the other is consuming a lot of memory [BlackBerry]

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-torch

In my application I have a requirement to navigate from one screen to another without popping up the active screen so that if a user clicks the back button while navigating he should be able to view the previous screens where he came from. I implemented this by pushing screens one by one in the UI stack but while doing so I saw that there is a considerable consumption of the memory. Can anyone tell me how can I minimize the memory used. In my app I saw that the memory is not released that much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The memory issue was not due to pushing so much screens to the display stack. I had some serious issues in my code due to which the resources were not releasing ending up in OutOfMemory exception.

I had corrected them and due to that my application is working well now. As far as I know now, there should not be any issues in pushing so many screens. It should work well.

Answer (score 1):

you can achieve it by this way .... it will work as you want.

```
ButtonField yourButton = new ButtonField("your Buton"){
         protected boolean navigationClick(int status, int time) {
               UiApplication.getUiApplication().
               popScreen(UiApplication.getUiApplication().getActiveScreen());
            return true;
            }
    };
```

Comment: This is not what I actually need. I have some serious issues with memory in my application. I called runtime.freememory() when each screen is being loaded and I found that each screen is consuming 4-5 MB. When it reaches around 290 MB (initially it was 360 MB) then the app is getting hang. But still I have 290 MB of memory. What could be the reason for this hang? Is that something related to threads?

Comment: This actually the code for which you can get the `back button` working it take you to the `previous active screen` ... But i haven't know about the memory issue... if i required anything like pressing back button should go to the previous screen or any thing like that i use this code.....